# What are these green and black marks in my tallow?

Tags: fat

I bought some tallow, used it a few times then left it in the fridge for a few months.  As you can see in the pic it has developed some green and black spots.

What are these and what caused it?  Is it safe for consumption?  Can I discard the coloured bits and use the rest of the tallow?[image][image]

Comment: Hard to tell from pic...mold would be my guess.

Comment: @moscafj I think i should not have put it in the fridge then.  I guess I should just discard it and it cannot really be salvaged?

Comment: Looks like spoon marks.  Maybe cross-contamination.